# Angular API Call on C# Web API Cors Exception

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, connection-close

I am trying to make an API Call on my C# Web API from my Angular Frontend.
I have tried it by HTTP and HTTPS.

HTTP: I am getting a CORS exception
HTTPS: I am getting a CONNECTION CLOSED EXCEPTION

I also have tried it via Postman and it worked so the Backend should not be the Problem.

I am using the Angular HTTP Client.

Answer (score 1):

in your Startup.cs file in the ConfigureServices there must exist the following code

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) method.
{
                services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                  builder => builder
                  .WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200", "YOUR_REQUEST_ORIGIN_URI")
                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                  .AllowCredentials()));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cors is security of browser, without cors configuration in api work it on postman,  postman is not a web browser.

Try adding Cors configuration, on your api

1. [AspNet Web API]

Install package

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`

Edit WebApiConfig file, in *App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs*

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        //change www.example.com for you domain, like localhost
        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("www.example.com", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
}
```

2. [.Net Core]

Edit *Startup.cs* and add CORS middleware and service

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddDefaultPolicy(
                builder =>
                {
                    //change www.example.com for you domain, like localhost
                    builder.WithOrigins("http://example.com");
                });
        });

        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

References

[AspNet WebApi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)
[.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-5.0)